# Purging Debian dpkg-deb config information complately

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, debian, dpkg, debconf

I am creating a debian package (.deb)
I wanted to get answer to some questions.
Somehow, installation of newly created .deb file was not asking question after asking once, even if package is purged
Setting question priority critical does not help
How can remove old answers totally?
This is important during package creation page

Comment: Note: priority critical really do not help. You should set to `low`, to get the questions. I think very few questions may be "critical" (if any, after installation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to remove all of your package's questions from debconf's database is to call `db_purge` in your `postrm` script, when removing or purging the package.

You have to previously load the debconf library:

`. /usr/share/debconf/confmodule`

For example:

```bash
#! /bin/sh

set -e

# Source debconf library.
. /usr/share/debconf/confmodule

case "$1" in
    remove|purge)

        # Remove all package's questions from debconf's database.
        db_purge
    ;;

    *)
        exit 0
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Answer (score -1):

After a bit of search I found that, debconf  stores answers in /var/cache/debconf/config.dat.
Open it, search for the concerned package and remove all details from this file.